# Converting char to int '23' > 23

Tags: c++, char, int, typeconverter

I have seen so many post of how to convert a single digit into an int, but how i can convert more than one digit number into a int, just like '23' convert it to 23;

Comment: [`std::stoi()` et al.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a char array to an integer, use `atoi()`. If converting strings, add `.c_str()` after the string variable to convert it into a suitable form for use.

You can also use `stoi()`, which provides some additional features for conversion, such as specifying the base.

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in function [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), or write your own implementation, eg.:

```
// A simple C++ program for implementation of atoi
#include <stdio.h>

// A simple atoi() function
int myAtoi(char *str)
{
    int res = 0; // Initialize result

    // Iterate through all characters of input string and update result
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        res = res*10 + str[i] - '0';

    // return result.
    return res;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    char str[] = "89789";
    int val = myAtoi(str);
    printf ("%d ", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/